# Change notification email, avatar and username but preserving all questions and score

Tags: support, stack-exchange, email-notification, profile-picture

Is it possible? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Go to your profile on the site you want to change the details on, and click "edit", which is next to your username. Your avatar is provided by Gravatar and based on the email address you give Stack Exchange (don't worry—it's a secret), so you'll have to change it at [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com/).